# How do you use the AT command?

Tags: batch-file, command, at-job

I would count myself as a intermediate programmer but for some reason I don't know how to use the `AT` command. What is it? How do I use it? Can someone show me an example of the `AT` command in a BATCH file?  Thanks, Jake

Answer (score 1):

`at` schedules tasks for deferred or repeated execution. As for how to use it – isn't the syntax description of the command itself not enough?

```
AT [\\computername] [ [id] [/DELETE] | /DELETE [/YES]]
AT [\\computername] time [/INTERACTIVE]
    [ /EVERY:date[,...] | /NEXT:date[,...]] "command"
```

In any case, [the documentation on TechNet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490866.aspx) has examples.

The easiest way is certainly just a single time when you need to run something:

```
at 19:35 "foo"
```

However, if you need more flexibility when scheduling tasks you should consider using `schtasks` instead. For example, you can only use `at` as a local administrator and `schtasks` can do everything `at` can do and more.